how to make pdf in hugging face space environment?
Recently I wondered how can I make pdf report of HTML script that was embedded in my python code.
I tried with pdfkit and obviusly wkhtmltopdf that is needed but that went terrible. I'm telling you. that's not gonna work. because you maybe don't have problem with installing pdfkit but I am sure you will have problem with installing wkhtmltopdf. because this one need's 'apt' instruction to be installled and 'apt' does not work in this environment.
**I recomend you to use weasyprint for converting HTML to PDF. that's it. just don't waste your time with pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf.
also weasyprint is very easy to use. follow this instruction in hugging face space environment:

put 'weasyprint' in your requirements.txt
you can use this scrip(for example) in your app.py:**

from weasyprint import HTML

# Converting HTML to PDF
html = HTML(string="<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>")
html.write_pdf("/path/to/output.pdf")


So what’s the question your have on your task?
